# Deleting an account(website) from Google Analytics?

Tags: google, account-management, google-analytics, delete

Where exactly is the option to remove an account in Google Analytics? I have checked several of the settings tabs and I am still unable to locate the delete option.

Comment: Account or website profile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Go to `https://www.google.com/analytics`
2. Click the profile that you want to edit
3. Click `Admin` on the right hand side of the screen

[image]

1. Click the name of the profile from the `profiles` tab
2. Click the `profile settings` tab

[image]

1. On the bottom right of the screen click the `Delete this profile` link and go through the confirmation steps

[image]

**Note** that this will permanently delete that profile and all data associated with it. If this profile is used by others and you just want to remove it from your list of profiles than you should ask another Administrator to remove you from the list of users.

Comment: ahh.. thanks @eduardocereto I think google warns you about the same things, but asking to be removed from the list of users is a great point.